# Index is not getting applied on Indexed View

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view, clustered-index, indexed-view

I have an indexed view but when I run queries on that view the index which is built on View is not applied and the query runs without index. Below is my dummy script:
Tables + View+ Index on View

```
CREATE TABLE P_Test
  (
     [PID]      INT IDENTITY,
     [TID]      INT,
     [StatusID] INT
  )

CREATE TABLE T_Test
  (
     [TID] INT IDENTITY,
     [FID] INT,
  )

CREATE TABLE F_Test
  (
     [FID]      INT IDENTITY,
     [StatusID] INT
  )

GO

INSERT INTO F_Test
SELECT TOP 1000 ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) %10) --below 100
FROM   master..spt_values

INSERT INTO T_Test
SELECT TOP 10000 ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) %1000) --below 1000
FROM   master..spt_values,
       master..spt_values v2

INSERT INTO P_Test
SELECT TOP 100000 ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) %10000) --below 10000
                  ,
                  ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) %10)--below 10
FROM   master..spt_values,
       master..spt_values v2

GO

CREATE VIEW [TestView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT P.StatusID AS PStatusID,
         F.StatusID AS FStatusID,
         P.PID
  FROM   dbo.P_Test P
         INNER JOIN dbo.T_Test T
           ON T.TID = P.TID
         INNER JOIN dbo.F_Test F
           ON T.FID = F.FID

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_TestView]
  ON [dbo].[TestView] ( [PStatusID] ASC, [FStatusID] ASC, [PID] ASC )
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Now when I run the following queries the [PK_TestView] index is not being applied:

```
    SELECT PStatusID ,
        FStatusID ,
        PID  FROM [TestView] 

SELECT PStatusID ,
        FStatusID ,
        PID  FROM [TestView] 
WHERE [PStatusID]=1

SELECT COUNT(PStatusID) FROM [TestView] 
WHERE [PStatusID]=1
```

Can you help me fixing this?

Comment: Maybe the optimizer just determines that the index is of no use for your queries?

Comment: @fge - No that isn't it. The OP has no useful index on `PStatusID` or to do the joins otherwise so the indexed view is much cheaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `NOEXPAND` hint. SQL Server will not consider matching indexed views without this (even if the view name is referenced in the query) unless you are on Enterprise Edition engine.

```
SELECT COUNT(PStatusID) 
FROM [TestView] 
     WITH (NOEXPAND) -- this line
WHERE [PStatusID]=1
```

This should give you the first, much cheaper, plan

[image: Plan]

Comment: Yes it worked!, Just curious, Is there any negative side of using NOEXPAND?

Comment: @RockySingh - Only that it means SQL Server can't consider **not** using the view.