# SQL Server Views - Index Usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Index is not getting applied on Indexed View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700126/index-is-not-getting-applied-on-indexed-view)

Is there a way to make the views to use only the index that I created on them, and not the ones on the base tables?

Comment: What is your SQL Server edition?